# Do all devatas work under Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, yama, devatas

Since Vishnu is operator (sanchalak) of the universe.

Do all devatas work under Vishnu ?

Does Yama also work under Vishnu ?

Comment: yes. Vishnu = owner. brahma = ceo. shiva = coo. indra = MD. vayu, agni, varuna, yama, kubera = VPs. all are posts except Vishnu. each manvantara or kalpa or pralaya, new jivatmas get promoted into these posts. e.g. indra rules for 14 manvantaras, after that Mahabali becomes next indra. shiva rules for 1 pralaya after that ashvatthama becomes next shiva. hanuman is next brahma. so on..

Comment: Ashwattha is next Vyasa. **Which scripture says that Ashwatthama is next Shiva.???** I m asking this because i have heard this statement earlier also (i think from u only,) but not any scriptural reference. Whereas Mahabharata n other states Vishnu is a post like ceo. Brahma is the company itself and Rudra is the owner and so on. Prd.. **Anyways rest thing we can differ from different different scriptures but can u kindly refer me the scriptural source about the Ashwatthama theory, Hanuman one is there in V.R. i know that.** I will be looking forward for that ...

Comment: C'mon man reply last time also u didn't give me any reference. It's like me saying Parshurama or Krishna Dwaipayana or even me being the next Vishnu after Pralaya without any proper scriptural reference. I think after some time, if i don't get any pro ref from u, i should ask a question about this here. That seems right decision. Prd..