# Scriptural Reference for the following below statement marked in bold

Tags: shiva, reference-request, kalpa, ashwatthama, pralaya

An User in [his comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58149/do-all-devatas-work-under-vishnu#comment175331_58149) says the following.:

> yes. Vishnu = owner. brahma = ceo. shiva = coo. indra = MD. vayu, agni, varuna, yama, kubera = VPs. all are posts except Vishnu. each manvantara or kalpa or pralaya, new jivatmas get promoted into these posts. e.g. indra rules for 14 manvantaras, after that Mahabali becomes next indra. **shiva rules for 1 pralaya after that ashvatthama becomes next shiva.** hanuman is next brahma. so on.. –
> **ram**

The Screen Shot.:

[image]

**So, does this statement about Ashwatthama, marked in bold have any scriptural reference.?**

Cz this is the second time i am hearing this statement from the same user. Last time he didn't answer when i asked him the source and this i don't know if he has seen my comment or not so asking this question. If anyone knows anything about it. AFAIK, Ashwatthama will be the next Vyasa and will among Sapta Rishis along with Krishna Dwaipayana and Parshurama in next Kalpa.